# Returning SAML status from Keycloak custom authenticator

Tags: authentication, keycloak, saml

I'm trying to implement a custom authenticator for Keycloak where, when authentication fails I set context.failure(AuthenticationFlowError.ACCESS_DENIED)

```
public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
    KeycloakSession session = context.getSession();

    //
    // authentication logic here
    //

    if (authnFailed)) {
        context.failure(AuthenticationFlowError.ACCESS_DENIED);
    }  else {
        context.success();
    }
```

I would expect Keycloak to return SAML response with the error status but instead it generates an internalexception. I need to it to return something like this:

```
<saml2:Response>
    <saml2:StatusCode Value=“urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester”>
        <saml2:StatusCode Value=“urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:AuthnFailed” />
    </saml2:StatusCode>
    <saml2:StatusMessageAccess Denied.</saml2p:StatusMessage>
  </saml2:Status>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Can this be accomplished? How?

Comment: I got a bit further getting rid of the exception by replacing context.failure(AuthenticationFlowError.ACCESS_DENIED); with          Response response = context.form().setError("Authentication failure").createCode();
         context.failure(AuthenticationFlowError.ACCESS_DENIED, response); but it only generated an error page with "Authentication failure" message. No SAML response.